# How to update jquery data table column values upon selecting the jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, datatables

I have a task to be implemented in which I need to implement jqgrid and upon selecting each row of the jqgrid the jquery data table column values should be updated with the grid values. Please help if any possible solution.

Comment: Please read the documentation/getting started guide of jQGrid and you should be able to do it. If you run into a specific error, you may post a question with relevant details and minimal code needed for reproducing the problem.  Please read [this](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jqgrid` `getRowData` function in `onSelectRow` event to get row data. And then use `row.add` function to add jqgrid's selected row to `DataTable` like following.

```
onSelectRow: function(rowId){ 
  var rowData = $("#list").getRowData(rowId);
  dataTable.row.add([ rowData['id'], rowData['name'] ] ).draw( false );
}
```

#### [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/azim101/0h95Ltps/)